# Spring Boot Security CAS Authentication Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cas

I am in desperate need of help. So as a prerequisite I am tasked with creating a simple web application. The application requirements are to create a simple web form that collects user data and then sends an email verification to the user that just provided information. The difficult aspect of this project is CAS Integration with the Marist College CAS authentication system. A requirement of this project was that I use Spring Boot to create the project. At the moment I have already implemented Spring Security to authenticate users. I have been trying everything online to integrate CAS with my existing project. I was hoping that someone on StackOverflow may have more knowledge on how to integrate CAS with SpringSecurtiy. Also please don't be harsh on me I have never used the spring framework before this project and this is all new to me. The Url of the CAS server is "https://login.marist.edu/cas/". I have looked into https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client spring support I just don't know how to integrate it with my current application. Thank you to anyone in advance that lends me a hand with this.

Comment: I think [this section](https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client#spring-boot-autoconfiguration) is pretty straight forward. You add the maven or gradle dependency, annotate Spring Boot application (or any @Configuration class) with `@EnableCasClient annotation` and provide cas related application properties. It would be easier to help you if you provide your effort and its results.

Comment: @leopal this was exactly what I was missing. Thank you for your help I will post a detailed answer to this question with my code once I have it completely configured.

Answer (score 1):

As I previously stated I would provide the solution to the problem that I experienced during the processes of integrating a spring application with the Marist CAS 2.0 Authentication System. As Stated above there is a Spring Boot AutoConfiguration that can be used. While this may not be the best method for securing your application it satisfied my needs for the project that I was working on. The Steps to configure your spring application with CAS 2.0 are bellow.

1. Add Maven Dependency

Maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
   <artifactId>cas-client-support-springboot</artifactId>
   <version>${java.cas.client.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Add the following required properties in Spring Boot's application.properties or application.yml

```
cas.server-url-prefix=https://cashost.com/cas
cas.server-login-url=https://cashost.com/cas/login
cas.client-host-url=https://casclient.com
```

3)Annotate Spring Boot application (or any @Configuration class) with @EnableCasClient annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@EnableCasClient
public class MyApplication { .. }
```

4)For CAS3 protocol (authentication and validation filters) - which is default if nothing is specified

```
cas.validation-type=CAS3
```

For CAS2 protocol (authentication and validation filters)

```
cas.validation-type=CAS
```

For SAML protocol (authentication and validation filters)

```
cas.validation-type=SAML
```

Comment: In spring boot is it needed spring validation filter?